# Most natural way of asking your wife/girlfriend to do a favor (make dinner)

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms

I have a small argument about what is the most natural way, in English,  to ask your wife/girlfriend to make a dinner for you (or do a different comparable favor).

Example situation: you're with your wife/girlfriend at home, maybe you have an option go out, but you really like her food and don't want to go out tonight. Your preference for today is stay at home, so you want her to cook the dinner. Of course you want to ask really nicely.

So you approach your wife/girlfriend and say ...

My version is:

> Will you make me a dinner, honey?

His version:

> I'd rather you made dinner now.

But what is the right one? What an native speaker would likely say?

Notes:

1. The question is purely abstract and is not about relationship advice. To be honest our wifes don't even speak English. He was practicing some grammar rules in English and asked this question to me and said my version is rude, while I feel like it's exactly the opposite.
2. I'm interested in how to form question correctly in this particular and similar situations, especially asking wife/girlfriend. Should it be "Could you"/"Would you"/"Can you"/"Will you"/"I'd rather"/"I prefer"/something else? Which one will be the best fit and what's the difference?

Comment: Your best option is the option that your wife/girlfriend prefers.

Comment: His version definitely will not come off nicely; it will come off more like a demand. Your's is nice, but I usually try to add a please in there, as it usually adds to the politeness.

Comment: Define *most natural*. Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: On reflection the best option is "Why don't I make dinner tonight, honey?"

Comment: @DJClayworth the problem is, if you don't cook, it can sound like a threat :D

Comment: @Drew well from my point of view (as a non-native), most natural is what an average native speaker would use most likely in this situation. You could try proposing your version and then perhaps the more upvotes it gets the more natural it is?

Comment: The problem with the first - "Will you make me a dinner,Honey?" is the indefinite article "a" which underlines the fact that this dinner may happen within hours or weeks.  "I'd rather you make dinner now," nails down the mealtime with the club of a caveman.  Both requests would work fine if you add "If you don't mind," at the beginning and omit the open-ended and "now" time frames and replace them with "tonight".

Comment: I think the most common way to ask someone to do something is to put it in the form of a question, as you have done. Your friend's approach is more abrupt - he simply states his wishes, and expects his wife to comply with what he wants. Personally I much prefer your friend's approach, it's just that my wife shows no inclination to fall in with my wishes. If your  friend finds his approach works then I envy him. I think you should be aware though that English-speaking countries have some of the highest divorce rates in the world. Do you really want relationship advice from us?

Comment: Just ask if she would mind cooking. "Make me a dinner" says that she cooks, you eat, and you like it that way. Wouldn't she cook dinner 'for us'? This is nice: "How about if you cooked? I like your food."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is fails many requirements for a good ELU/SE question. It is too broad, it is opinion-based, there are no specifications as to what is desired in  'choosing and ideal word or phrase'. And most important of all, it is relationship advice and not really about any particular English phrases or idioms. It might be fixable if it avoids all those problems.

Comment: @Mitch 1) How come it is too broad? There's a particular context described, and I'm asking for help with choosing a phrase that fits it best. 2) Opinion based? How does it differ from any other word/phrase choice question? 3) It is not relationship advice at all because both me and my friend have wifes who don't even speak English. We were arguing about an abstract situation

Comment: 1) too broad because there are an infinite variety of possible answers 2) opinion based because we have no way of judging what is the best one (single word and phrase requests are also problematic here for that reason) 3) The judgment is all on social psychology not on language forms.

Comment: I edited the question even though I really don't get the problem. It's a simple phrase choice question, I saw a number of similar here, and why it is considered by so many to be unfitting is a complete mystery for me. If it is still bad, please advice how exactly I should change it.

Comment: @Mitch, 1) Well then I don't understand what's the whole point of word/phrase choice questions. Each one of those can have infinite number of possible answers. 2) & 3) Well somehow davidlol managed to publish a great (in my opinion) answer to this question (see below), with good grounding and without referring to social psychology ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cambridge university dictionary has a web page on [making requests in English](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/functions/requests).

It says that the most common way in English to make a request is in the form of a question. It gives examples of polite usage (I have amended the actual request to suit the dining dilemma faced by OP and his friend).

> Could you make dinner tonight, please?
>
> Would you make dinner tonight, please
>
> Would you mind making dinner tonight, please?
>
> Do you think you could make dinner tonight, please?

It goes on to say that a more informal way of asking is:

> Can you make dinner tonight?

or

> Will you make dinner tonight?

It then goes on to give an example of how a polite boss night make a request (give an instruction).

> We need you to cook dinner tonight.

Saying I want is very direct and can be impolite.

> I want you to cook dinner tonight.

Another option is not to make a request but to give a command.

> Cook the dinner.

**Conclusion**

Your approach, "Will you make me  a dinner tonight?",  is polite and informal.

Your friend's approach, "I'd rather you made dinner now", is closest to "I want" which is described as very direct and may be impolite.

I do not know what sort of relationship you and your friend have with your respective wives or girlfriends but if but if it is informal and polite (like most, I think) then your version is best, but if it is such that you speak very directly with no need for too much politeness, either because it is not intended or because it is assumed, then your friend's version is best.

If the relationship is polite but more formal then try "could you make dinner tonight, please".  If you come from a culture where women do as they are told he simple command will be more appropriate.

I'd write more but my wife wants me to cook the dinner.